# Найти квадраты в массиве

Tags: java, c++, python, c

Есть двумерный массив, нужно найти самый большой квадрат из этого массива, у которого на диагоналях числа будут меньше введенного числа. [image] получается программа должна найти все такие квадратики и выбрать самый большой, ведь квадратики могут быть и слева и ниже. Пока что я  сделал только так

```
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader("Vopsea.in.txt"));
            int n = reader.nextInt();
            int m = reader.nextInt();
            int arr[][] = new int[n][m];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    arr[i][j] = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Введите число которого не должны достигать диагонали:  ");
            int h = Only.onlyInt(scanner);
            int arr1[][];
            int arr2[][];
            int lun = 0;
            if(n>m)
                lun = m+1;
            else if(m>n)
                lun = n+1;
            else
                lun=n+1;
            int l = lun;
            int l1 = lun;
            while(true){
                l-=1;
                int k = 0;
                arr1 = new int[l][l];
                for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
                    for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
                        arr1[i][j] = arr[i][j];

                for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++){
                        if(i==j && arr1[i][j]<h)
                            k++;
                    }
                }
                int v = l-1;
                for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
                    if(arr1[i][v] < h)
                        k++;
                    v--;
                }
                if(k==l*2)
                    break;
            }
```

То есть у меня программа ищет квадрат только с правого нижнего угла до левого верхнего

Comment: Тестируй просто диагонали - квадрат сам вылезет.

Comment: Зачем задавать один и тот же вопрос 2 раза?

Comment: самый большой по размеру? если будет таких будет больше одного?

Comment: @Maggot тут более детально задан вопрос)

Comment: @slippyk нужно найти самый большой по размеру, но если их больше то вывести все с наибольшим размером